# Center pictures inside div

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I am allowed to apply only inline css. I have a html file where I display some logos. I tried 'text-align center' in every block as well as 'margin: 0 auto' styles. But it still doesn't come to center horizontally.

Here is sample of my Html code:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; float: left; background-color: #a30074;margin:auto">
     <h2 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0px;">OUR CLIENTS</h2>
     <hr style="width: 10%; margin-bottom: 0px; border-color: #a0a0a0;">
     <hr style="width: 10%; margin-top: 1px; border-color: #a0a0a0;">
      <!--Container-->
    <div style="margin:auto">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Our VAT Clients</h3>
        <div style="width: 150px; float: left; margin: auto; display: block;">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xAeCka9.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 150px; float: left; margin: auto; display: block;">
           <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iXSZMRM.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 150px; float: left; margin: auto; display:block;">
           <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ivoEjnQ.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the floats, use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for the image containers.

```html
<div style="background-color: #a30074;">
  <h2 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0px;">OUR CLIENTS</h2>
  <hr style="width: 10%; margin-bottom: 0px; border-color: #a0a0a0;">
  <hr style="width: 10%; margin-top: 1px; border-color: #a0a0a0;">
  <!--Container-->
  <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center;">Our VAT Clients</h3>
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; display:flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div style="width: 150px;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xAeCka9.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 150px;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iXSZMRM.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ivoEjnQ.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the floats. `text-align:center;` on the wrapper.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; float: left; background-color: #a30074;margin:auto">
    <h2 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0px;">OUR CLIENTS</h2>
    <hr style="width: 10%; margin-bottom: 0px; border-color: #a0a0a0;">
    <hr style="width: 10%; margin-top: 1px; border-color: #a0a0a0;">
    <!--Container-->
    <div style="margin:auto; text-align:center;">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Our VAT Clients</h3>
        <div style="width: 150px; display:inline-block; margin: auto;">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xAeCka9.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 150px; display:inline-block; margin: auto; ">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iXSZMRM.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 150px; display:inline-block; margin: auto;">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ivoEjnQ.png" alt="Client" width="149px">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="text-align:center"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ivoEjnQ.png" /></p>
```

Try this code